# ios change the tabbaritem's badge in the AppDelegate

Tags: badge

oh! i try to change the badge of `tabbarItem` in the `AppDelegate`;then  it do work, but the `tabarItem` doesn't show!  my code ：

```
 UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainIdentifier"];

    [[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setBadgeValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"199"]];
```

(i also see the site [How to set tabBarItem's badge from AppDelegate.m (tabBarView is not root View)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129260/how-to-set-tabbaritems-badge-from-appdelegate-m-tabbarview-is-not-root-view))

Answer (score 1):

You can upvote the original answer [here by Jim Rota](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854357/best-way-to-update-badgevalue-of-uitabbarcontroller-from-a-uiview)

Access Tab Bar Controller:"

```
UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```

Then set the badge

```
[[tabController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] tabBarItem].badgeValue = @"New!";
```